# two numbers chosen from 0 to 1, expected val of larger number

Tags: combinatorics, expected-value

If I pick two numbers in the interval (0,1), what is the expected value of the larger number?

Please help. I know that the expected value of one number is 0.5 but I'm not sure how to find the expected vlaue of the larger number here.

Comment: I am going to take a wild guess, which could easily be **wrong**, based on Bayes Theorem: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (i/n)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n (i/n)}.$$  The idea is that the denominator represents the sum of the probabilities of all the intervals, and the numerator weights each interval with the actual value associated with that interval.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that the value of the larger number is $x$. The probability of this is equal to the probability that the other number is less than $x$. This probability is obviously $x $. Therefore the expected value of the larger number is:
$$2\int_0^1 x\cdot x\, dx=\frac23,
$$
where the factor 2 counts the ways to choose the larger number.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the scenario with two die:

```
6 6 6 6 6 6
5 5 5 5 5 6
4 4 4 4 5 6
3 3 3 4 5 6
2 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

The expected value here is:

$$\frac{1+6+15+28+45+66}{36}=\frac{161}{36}=4.47\dot2$$

$161$ is the sixth term in the sequence of hexagonal pyramid numbers ([$A002412$](https://oeis.org/A002412)).

These are given by:

$$\frac{n(n+1)(4n-1)}{6}$$

On the unit grid, we can do a similar trick. However if say we use a resolution of $k$, then to calculate the expectation we use $kP(X=k)$, and over $k^2$ squares, to give the result as:

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{k(k+1)(4k-1)}{6k^3}=\frac23$$